# How to add a ActionListener to the AWT MenuItem?

Tags: java, awt, menuitem

Thanks for your attention!
PLease help a newbie out :)

Current Problem:

Need to change a color of the line when clicking on a MenuItem with the name of the color.

Here is my code for changing the color of the line.
When i create the menuItems i also crete the actionListener for them:

```
private void CreateMenu()
{
    menuBar = new MenuBar();
    menu = new Menu("File");
    mSave = new MenuItem("Save");
    colorSubMenu = new Menu("Choose Color...");

    String[] colors = {"red","yellow","green","blue","purple","black"};
    for(int i=0;i<colors.length;i++)
    {
        final int ii = i;
        MenuItem m=new MenuItem(colors[i]);
        colorSubMenu.add(m);
        colorSubMenu.addActionListener(
                                    new ActionListener()
                                            {
                                                @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                                                {
                                       THIS LINE DOESN'T WORK ===>> color = Color.getColor(colorSubMenu.getItem(ii)));
                                                }
                                             }
                                        );
    }

    menu.add(mSave);        
    menu.add(colorSubMenu);
    menuBar.add(menu);        
    setMenuBar(menuBar);
}
```

But... it doesn't work!
please give an advise. i am running out of ideas.

Will be glad to hear anything:) thanks once again!

UPDATE:

want to change this part to something more elegant and that actually works:

```
colorSubMenu.addActionListener(
   new ActionListener()
   {
      @Override 
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
THIS LINE DOESN'T WORK ===>> color = Color.getColor(colorSubMenu.getItem(ii)));
      }
   }
);
```

Comment: Are you using awt for something special? You can use swing.

Comment: What line are you talking about?

Comment: pardon for been unlclear @durron597 - i need to create the code to substitute the current line color with the one chosen from the colorSubMenu (colorSubMenu contains menuItems named red,black,blue and so on), i tryed this but doesn't work

Comment: @GrimSmiler still not clear, what _line_? where?

Comment: @nachokk, i'd love to use swing but the lab has to be made with AWT :)

Comment: @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                                                {
                                                    /*here I should somehow change the global color variable for the line*/
                                                }

Comment: There is no **line** anywhere in your code. We can't help you if we don't know what you're talking about

Comment: updated the code - sorry for been slow :)

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Answer (score 1):

[`Color#getColor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getColor%28java.lang.String%29) relys on using colors from the System properties. These probably will not match the colors from the Color array in the question. You can use reflection instead

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Field field = Class.forName ("java.awt.Color").getField (e.getActionCommand());
    Color color = (Color) field.get (null);
    // use color...
}
```

Comment: please, tell me what does getActionCommand do? i did look in the Oracle documentation :) does it return the value stored by the item that caused the action?

Comment: _Returns the command string associated with this action_. I found this in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html#getActionCommand())